# why did windows updates install at 2:30pm instead of the time configured in the registry

Tags: windows, wsus, windows-update, windows-registry

I have a server in a multi-tenant environment using a WSUS server outside of the domain that the server resides in.  Here is the current configuration for the WSUS settings:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate]
"WUServer"="http://xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxx.net""
"WUStatusServer"="http://xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxx.net"
"DisableWindowsUpdateAccess"=dword:00000000
"TargetGroup"="Dedicated 1"
"TargetGroupEnabled"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU]
"ScheduledInstallTime"=dword:00000003
"ScheduledInstallDay"=dword:00000004
"AUOptions"=dword:00000004
"UseWUServer"=dword:00000001
"RebootWarningTimeout"=dword:00000005
```

This is a client server that I don't access unless to manage or troubleshoot.  This is has Server 2012 running as the OS, so I know that there were changes to the way that Windows 8/2012 handle Windows Update.  Those types of changes do not account for the fact that this server rebooted at 2:30PM whereas the updates were scheduled to take place at 3:00AM today.  The server is obviously online during this time and was actively being used by the client.  I thought about making the change to have it never reboot while there are users logged onto the server but that doesn't really "fix" the issue at hand.

The other thought is that the client may have had one of their developers accidentally reboot the server, that's a possibility.

Any assistance or guidance on altering the registry settings would be greatly appreciated here.  Also making mention of using a group policy over registry is not necessarily the best option as we do not manage their domain.

Thanks,

Comment: "The other thought is that the client may have had one of their developers accidentally reboot the server, that's a possibility."  Never ascribe to technical failure that which is adequately explained by stupid developers.

Comment: Have you confirmed by analyzing the Windows Update log that it was in fact Windows Update that initiated the reboot?

Comment: Yes.  I have confirmed that the server was rebooted on behalf of the System account at the same time that windows updates were applied on the server.

Comment: Also, I can't "really" go back to my client and say that a stupid developer caused his server to reboot during production.  However, I have told the client that it may have been caused by someone else logged into the server.  That is the only logical explanation that I can come up with.

Answer (score 2):

> I thought about making the change to have it never reboot while there
>   are users logged onto the server but that doesn't really "fix" the
>   issue at hand.

You probably *don't* want the "no auto reboot with logged in user" enabled.  This can cause behavior where an update is applied while someone is connected to the server, and when the user logs off the server reboots.  Even if it's the middle of the production day.

In fact, that's what I suspect happened.

> The other thought is that the client may have had one of their
>   developers accidentally reboot the server, that's a possibility.

If a dev or admin was logged in while updates were applied and logged out at 2:30pm, that could cause the server to reboot, yes.

Comment: No the client was logged into the server and then the server kicked him off for a reboot of the server.  This reboot was on behalf of the System account and was at the same time as updates were applied to the server.  Your first comment makes a lot of sense, and I don't feel it would be the best way to go as there may be other clients that never log out of their server.